# Flask send_from_directory returns 404 for certain filenames

Tags: python, flask

let me show you an example:

This is the folder that I want to send the files from:

```
app.config['DOWNLOAD_FOLDER'] = os.path.join(app.root_path, 'downloads')
```

I return the files like this from the route:

```
return send_from_directory(app.config['DOWNLOAD_FOLDER'], song_title,as_attachment=True)
```

I get 404 for certain files such as:

> Baby Shark Dance _ Most Viewed Video on YouTube _ PINKFONG Songs for Children.mp3

> 'E.T.' - Katy Perry (Rock Cover by First To Eleven).mp3

It works perfectly fine for these:

> The Witcher Soundtrack - Toss A Coin To Your Witcher Lyrics.mp3

> Yung Felix - Loco ft. Poke & Dopebwoy.mp3

I tried to place the song_title in a formatted raw string like this:

```
return send_from_directory(app.config['DOWNLOAD_FOLDER'], r"{}".format(song_title), as_attachment=True)
```

It didn't work.

Here is the entire route function:

```
    @app.route('/home', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def home():

    if request.method == 'POST':
        
        song_name = request.form.get('songname')
        song_url, song_title = get_youtube_url_from_name(song_name)
        song_title = song_title + '.mp3'
        download_mp3_from_url(song_url)
        return send_from_directory(app.config['DOWNLOAD_FOLDER'], secure_filename(song_title),
                             as_attachment=True)
        # flash(song_title + ' has been successfully downloaded!')
        # return redirect(url_for('home'))

    return render_template('home.html')
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: where you able to solve this issue? Im having a similar problem but with images uploaded by the user.

Answer (score 0):

You can try **secure_filename** function for your application.

The function **secure_filename** will replace any whitespace of the user provided

filename with an underscore. The following code will be as shown in below:

```
song_title = secure_filename(song_title)

return send_from_directory(app.config['DOWNLOAD_FOLDER'], song_title,as_attachment=True)
```

Comment: I tried it and the problem still persists. Thanks for your time.